# kubectl top no not reflecting actual RAM

Tags: kubernetes

**Problem statement:**
Have kubernetes cluster with 32 GB RAM in worker node. After cluster setup we have upgraded to 64GB RAM.

> kubectl top no

command reflecting in memory but pod are going on pending status. % also showing more than 100%

```
NAME             CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
SERVERNAME_4v   308m         7%     10853Mi         68%
SERVERNAME_5v   331m         8%     10177Mi         64%
SERVERNAME_6v   357m         8%     9133Mi          57%
SERVERNAME_7v   548m         6%     33619Mi         105%
SERVERNAME_8v   748m         9%     31465Mi         98%
```

**kubernetes cluster**

```
kubernetes version : v1.19.0 and 
docker CE : 19.03.8
Metrics server: kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0
```

Comment: Can you provide details, output of $ kubectl describe no ?  Also please execute such command on pods  ($ kubectl describe pod pod-name) and provide output.

Comment: Do you have swap space disabled on the worker nodes?

Comment: @Malgorzata
**Capacity:**
  cpu:                8
  ephemeral-storage:  314415108Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             32761644Ki
  pods:               110

Comment: kubectl describe pod cronjob-claim-1605685140-gh2bc -n namespace

-----
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     10m
      memory:  10Mi

------


Events:
  Type     Reason            Age    From  Message
  ----     ------            ----   ----  -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4h38m        0/5 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory, 3 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.

Comment: @justin-tamblyn : Yes. disabled swap.

Comment: restart kubelet has fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer, also please edit post and add properly edited information I've asked for ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Kanthasamyraja Shanmugam wrote. Problem is solved by restarting [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/).

Execute command:

```
$ systemctl restart kubelet
```